# Release APK made based on master or current branch

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm wondering when you **Generate Signed APK** if Android studio does this based on the master branch version of the project or the current checked out branch?

I make sure to merge everything to master and generate from there anyway but I'm just curious.

Comment: check the current branch using `git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2` the name you see in Terminal of android studio will build using that branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio will generate the signed APK based on the checked out branch.

Source: tried it out.